# Clear output only printed by function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Consider the following script:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time

def func1():
    print('Func1 started.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 step1 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 step2 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 completed.')
    
def func2():
    print('Func2 started.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 step1 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 step2 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 completed.')

func1()
func2()
```

When I am running `func2`, the final output printed by `func1` gets deleted. Is there a way to keep "**Func1 completed.**" printed when running `func2`?

Comment: Are you trying to make the two functions rum simultaneously?

Comment: @blackbrandt No, the functions run in order. But sometimes I run func2 first. Then, of course "Func2 completed" should be printed when func1 is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can display in two differents outputs :

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, display
from ipywidgets import Output
import time

def func1():
    print('Func1 started.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 step1 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 step2 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func1 completed.')
    
def func2():
    print('Func2 started.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 step1 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 step2 completed.')
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output()
    print('Func2 completed.')


out1 = Output()
out2 = Output()

display(out1)
with out1:
    func1()
display(out2)
with out2:
    func2()
```

The outputs of the two functions will be displayed.